# Download previous version of Selenium jars?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jar

From where and how can I download the previous version of selenium jars? Currently I can download only selenium 3.0 from seleniumHQ. I need to download let's say 2.53 version of selenium.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html... Select the version you want from the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the dependency in your POM to use the appropriate version.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java

Comment: Thanks @martin, i was just trying to showcase basic sample project where i can add latest selenium jars without introducing maven as of now.